# Edit comment shows [object Object] instead of previous comment text

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, comments

When I try to edit my comment, the textbox shows `[object Object]` instead of the previous comment text. First time I've seen this. Xubuntu 16.04, Chrome 63.

Image of regular comment:

[image: screenshot 1]

Image of comment box after I click it:

[image: screenshot 2]

If you can't see the image, it should show:

```
What does this do? (I don't know Perl)
```

but it shows:

```
[object Object]
```

[Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33388075/2397327).

@SebastianSimon pointed out [this duplicate on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314305/edit-comment-yields-object-object-instead-of-comment-text), so it looks like it started very recently.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SE: [Edit comment yields `[object Object]` instead of comment text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314305/289905).

Comment: @Xufox Nice catch. I've never dealt with cross-site dupes before -- is there something I should do?

Comment: This started less than 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Yeah, i edited a comment an hour back or so and it was fine. Now when i tried to edit it, I get the [object Object] error.

Comment: a new comment bug again :p .. they really need to do more tests ...

Comment: Also reported on SU: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13266/editing-comment-issue

Comment: and on Math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28936/major-editing-bug

Comment: they have also changed the icon of comments ... there is more effect on them now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Cross post from [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314309/235711)**

> This is my fault, the fix is live now for MSE, building on the
>   network.
>
> In working on
>   [Keyboard-only users cannot flag comments in the new comment flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313761/keyboard-only-users-cannot-flag-comments-in-the-new-comment-flag-dialog/314306#314306),
>   I needed access to the event that showed the flagging dialog, so I
>   updated the comment UI hooks to pass in the event as the first
>   parameter.
>
> This was fine fo the various hooks, upvote, flag, etc, except for
>   edit, because the edit hook already had a parameter defined
>   `textOverride`.  So the event that was passed in was treated as a text
>   override and replaced the edit text.

Comment: and the new focus state on the comment icon is intentionnal or a side effect of something?

Comment: The fix is live for SO also. No longer getting [Object object] here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you're talking about upvote/flag, it's intentional.  They're now buttons and they're inheriting styles from the `.s-btn` class.  It was one option to make them keyboard/screen reader accessible.

Comment: @BrianNickel Can we get the outlines to go away after the relevant action's been taken? As is when using a mouse they're invisible until *after* you click the button and don't go away until you click something else.

Comment: @Draco18s I have a change in review right now that would reduce the highlighting considerably and prevent the icon color from turning that dark blue.  Turns out there was a mess of poorly interacting styles that needed to be cleaned up.  As far as making the highlight go away completely for mouse users, it looks like that's non-trivial and surrounded with browser quirks.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thanks for the reply. I'm disappointed, but appreciate the response.