# What's with the new comment buttons border?

Tags: support, feature-request, design

Today, I upvoted a comment (on Meta). I noticed that the upvote and flag icons have a light red background and a grey glow while the mouse was down. After I had upvoted, the grey glow persisted while a new black border appeared.
[image]

I tested it on the main site. The color scheme is worse – light orange background with bright blue border; dark blue when upvoted?

Can we disable or at least change the borders and glow?

Comment: something to do with the recent accessibility updates

Comment: I guess I'll make a userscript then

Comment: here is the reply : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372714/edit-comment-shows-object-object-instead-of-previous-comment-text/372720?noredirect=1#comment622248_372720

Comment: The black border does appear for the flag button, it just quickly disappear  when the focus comes to the flag dialog.

Comment: The outline around the upvote isn't great either, as it doesn't show up until *after* you've clicked it (why? It should, at most, be a *hover* effect).

Comment: I'm using Stylus to remove the borders, I highly recommend it.

Comment: @JacobG. That's what I am using right now.

Comment: Related: This is probably not SO/SE's problem but I thought I'd just mention it. I'm using [Darkness Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/darkness-beautiful-dark-t/imilbobhamcfahccagbncamhpnbkaenm) and when it's enabled, the upvote/flag buttons _on the main site_ started showing a pretty ugly border _when not pressed_ a few days ago. Example: 1. [Upvote button not pressed](https://s15.postimg.cc/dsibazmpn/normal.png), 2. [Upvote button pressed](https://s15.postimg.cc/84c0k3q2z/pressed.png).

Comment: @Ahmed That is a fluke in the extension's CSS. Try emailing them (support@darkness.app) and asking them to fix it.

Comment: @astonearachnid Yeah, I'll probably do that. I just thought that since it's _most likely_ caused by the new changes your post is discussing, contacting Darkness's support might not be necessary if SE would roll back these changes. But now it makes sense knowing that they changed it to a button as referred to in Temani's comment _which I only read after I posted mine_. It's unlikely that they would undo that, so yep, I'll probably contact Darkness about this.

Comment: Since these icons now take more vertical space, it creates a lot more white space between comments.

Comment: What is EFFING happening with the stackexchange sites - why are all these changes ruining OUR lives.

Comment: @JonH watch out with sarcasm because I'm told that gets stuff deleted nowadays.

Comment: Uggh, if I vote up then move my mouse away or just drag out with mouse down, I get the same effect - did I actually vote or not? Then, if I try to undo my click after 60 seconds, first time I get the usual "Can only undo within 60 seconds", but after that I get the same ugly after-click effect but no warning message. (Latest Opera on Windows 8)

Comment: I dont like the way it glows over the top row of pixels in the flag button

Answer (score 2):

AFAICS this feature does more harm than good:

- Very distracting: dark color and highlighting *with a border* (a border, even more so, a high-contrast one, is formatting traditionally reserved for the most important things on a page)
- It's pointless to prominently focus it: I cannot input anything into it or something
- A dark-colored triangle appearing as I click was prominent enough to see the effect as it was
- It looks vastly different than other comments that I upvoted before, suggesting some difference from them -- which is disinformation because there's no actual difference (and on the next visit, the comment looks normally)

All in all, a typical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good situation.

I guess the point for the change was probably to compensate for poor visibility of the triangle on some sites due to a choice of an [insufficiently contrasting color](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) -- but then, it's the color which is to blame. Maybe reserve this formatting to problematic sites if fixing the root cause (i.e. choosing a more contrasting color scheme) is too hard?