# Button outline overlapping while browsing questions

Tags: bug, design

There's a weird outline overlapping other buttons when you click on one of them.

[image]

Ew.

*PS: here is the more visible, inverted version :*

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372734/whats-with-the-new-comment-buttons-border

Comment: Doesn’t seem that disruptive. It’s only visible for a short period of time while the page loads. It only persists when you drag-and-drop it, as seen in the GIF. But… who actually does that?

Comment: @Xufox As someone who sometimes clicks too fast but realises it before I lift my finger, I often find myself "dropping" the link I clicked elsewhere, in order for it not to trigger. When this happens, the outline stays visible.

Comment: Did I break something again?

Comment: well, it was there since they update the responsive stuffs